# How can I remove the headers

Tags: linux, text-processing, iostat

I would like to remove both headers (that are incidentally repeated). Any solution for it?

```
[root@report]# iostat -xd 5
Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 (mdds-pgbackup-01)     07/05/2018      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.07     0.28    0.31    4.22     9.25    28.56    16.72     0.08   16.70   38.40   15.12   5.92   2.68
scd0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     7.99     0.00    0.88    0.88    0.00   0.88   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.28    3.01     8.86    28.13    22.50     0.05   16.58   41.32   14.27   8.11   2.67
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.09    0.11     0.38     0.43     8.04     0.00    6.45    8.44    4.72   1.00   0.02

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
scd0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

expected output:

```
[root@report]# iostat -xd 5


vda               0.07     0.28    0.31    4.22     9.25    28.56    16.72     0.08   16.70   38.40   15.12   5.92   2.68
scd0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     7.99     0.00    0.88    0.88    0.00   0.88   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.28    3.01     8.86    28.13    22.50     0.05   16.58   41.32   14.27   8.11   2.67
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.09    0.11     0.38     0.43     8.04     0.00    6.45    8.44    4.72   1.00   0.02


vda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
scd0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698229/how-to-remove-repeated-header-from-the-output-of-iostat-linux-command

Comment: Do you want to delete both of them or just the 2nd one?

Comment: I want both of them to be deleted

Comment: @Fayne, you should **accept** the answer that solved your problem, if any. Please, [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is just to use `egrep':

```
iostat -xd 5 | egrep -v "Linux|Device"
```

`egrep` prints lines with multiple strings via extended regular expressions and `-v` prints lines not containing those strings which, in this case, are "Linux" and "Device".

Output:

```
vda               0.07     0.28    0.31    4.22     9.25    28.56    16.72     0.08   16.70   38.40   15.12   5.92   2.68
scd0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     7.99     0.00    0.88    0.88    0.00   0.88   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.28    3.01     8.86    28.13    22.50     0.05   16.58   41.32   14.27   8.11   2.67
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.09    0.11     0.38     0.43     8.04     0.00    6.45    8.44    4.72   1.00   0.02


vda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
scd0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iostat -xd 5 | grep -v '/'
```

This would remove all lines from the output of `iostat` that contains a slash, which only the headers do.